# get a position in bindView using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

i am create a listview which has  two `TextView` and one custom view as a selection indicator , to load data i am using `CursorAdapter` and overriding `bindView` and `newView`. but the issue is in preserving the selection index.

when i am tapping a list item , i am saving the position of it into view as follows

```
View v1=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.viewColor);
v1.setTag(position)
```

but inside a `bindView` i not getting a position where i can perform a match by fetching position from view's tag as follows

```
 Integer position = (Integer) v1.getTag();
```

but i am not getting a position to compare just the way we get in `getView`. i tried cur.getPosition() is the position of a record in cursor which wont match with the v1.getTag().

i tried overriding getView as follows , but not getting accurate position

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    this.position = position;
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


}
```

so how i can i get the position in bindView ? do i need to use getView or what ? i explored many threads but i didn't get any definite answer when it comes to bindView.

EDIT

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {


                    view.setTag(position); 
                   // i save the position on list item click so that when adapter loads the 
                   // the list i can match the position with the current one

          }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For This first you need to override `getView()` and set the position here and access it in `bindview()` later.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
    if (convbertview == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your layout,
                null);
    }
    convertview.setTag(position);
    return super.getView(position, convbertview, arg2);
}
```

and in `bindView()` get your position like

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int position=(Integer) view.getTag();//here is the position

}
```

Comment: if i use convertView to store the position then , where i will store the position of item click ?

Comment: @Hunt sry..i didn't get u.expain clealy.

Comment: @Hunt in item click it will give you position.whats the problem??

Comment: @Hunt what you will do in onitemClick .why you need to save??

Comment: to maintain the sate of selected item , as i m changing the the row color when item is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67752/discussion-between-hunt-and-kalyan-pvs).

Comment: @Hunt maintain it in a ArrayList or in a SparcebooleanArray

Answer (score 2):

Don't override getView since you use CursorAdapter. You can register onClickListener in the bindView. Let's say you listen for tapping on the icon, then you do like this:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View vw, Context ctx, final Cursor cursor) {
    /* 
    *   do your binding
    */
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) vw.findViewById(R.id.your_icon);
    icon.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
    icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you pass right position to your activity
            ((MainActivity) context).onIconClick((int)v.getTag());  
        }
    });
}
```

In your activity just:

```
public void onIconClick(int position) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your onItemClick like below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mAdapter.setId(id);
    //Set the selector here
}
```

Then maintain one id variable in the adapter and write the setters and getters for it. then change your bindView() method as below

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    long tempId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    if(tempId==id){
        //Set the selector color here
    }
    else{
        //Set the default color here
    }

    //Remaing your logic here
}
```

In this way you no need to override getView() method.

If you want to select multiple views you have to maintain the ArrayList of ids...

Comment: cursor id is different from list item position.that too cursor will be changed dynamically based on user requirement like edittext search..

Comment: but the cursor position change.id is not equal to position.

Comment: ok..let me explain clearly. if u have list id with 10 at poisition 4,id with 11 at poisition 5.In bindview i need position of id 10..then how you will give?? by your answer i will get tempid as 10 but not 4.Op asked about position not id.

Comment: @Hunt intention is to maintaining the list selector.okay if you want position then maintain the position instead of _id and you will get the position in the bindView() by cursor.getPosition();

Comment: but he asked question with title as **get a position in bindView using CursorAdapter**

Answer (score 0):

Inside the "bindView" method but out of "onClickListener()":

1. `final int position = cursor.getPosition();`
2. Inside the "onClickListener()":

`cursor.moveToPosition(position); //retrieve any data you want after this`

Good luck~